# URL Rewrite Module for IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, reverse-proxy

Does anyone have experience using the URL Rewrite Module (see [here](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/07/09/new-iis7-releases-url-rewrite-application-routing-and-load-balancing-and-powershell-cmd-lets.aspx))?

Can it be used to do [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can not.  You have to use a tool like **.NET URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy**

http://codeplex.com/urlrewriter

It also supports IIS 6.0, and is accomplished completely through the .NET Framework.

Comment: It does support this although you need version 2 for the response rewriting: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 2):

That http://codeplex.com/urlrewriter is quite cool, as it supports [the standard mod_rewrite syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

We use the Microsoft IIS7 URL Rewriter here at SO with great success, though we did have to update to the newer Go-Live license version to get rid of some preview exceptions. Also it doesn't support mod_rewrite syntax, but there is a tool included to convert back and forth to Microsoft's XML based routing table format. (sigh, XML).

However it does not do reverse proxy as Nick noted. You may need to install [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1712) for IIS7 which apparently offers this feature..

Comment: Thanks Jeff, having you say it is cool, is a great compliment.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the reverse proxy by using both URL Rewrite Module and Application Request Routing module as explained in the article "[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite and Application Request Routing"](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/).